# What is the problem with this question?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I was recently on Stack Overflow and asked a question. It seemed to me to be fairly well formatted and an appropriate length. However soon after I asked it, it got downvoted. Now I do realize that downvoting and flagging are two very different things; but the people on Stack Overflow seem fairly well educated and they probably downvoted it for a reason, so I was wondering why.

> I need to read a very large json file full of english words from inside of a web application. I am using browserify and am wanting to export the object after it has been read and parsed. Because of this I want it to be read synchronously so that the other files that are dependant on the json file will not have to be configured to wait for the file to be read.
> My first thought was to use the fs module, but that was node specific. My next idea was to get a fs equivalent, but none of them seemed to have fs.readFileSync.
>
> **So, my question is:**
>
> How to synchronously read a file in the browsery using any method possible, but preferably with fs.readFileSync.

Comment: Why is a question soliciting an explanation about huma... user behavior is tagged support? Another of the wonders of life I suppose?

Comment: @Braiam I tagged it as discussion, it  was edited by a mod.

Comment: I know, I can see the revisions link, and I also deliberately replaced the tag. My question was more of a rhetorical one.

Comment: I can see how this question is asking for support in using the site.

Comment: Asking for help with a feature of the site, including asking good questions, is a support request, @Braiam. MilesZew isn't looking for discussion here. They're looking for an answer to their question: how can they improve their programming question and get good answers? These types of questions should be treated as support requests, and handled accordingly (in answers, votes, etc.).

Comment: @CodyGray I recommend you to visit several discussions on [specific-\*] and switch them to support then. "Using the site" is not this question, if you go down with it, *every* meta question is a support question. It boils down to "why was my question downvoted and how can I improve it".

Comment: Yes, "how can I improve my question?" is a support request. Some time when I have nothing else to do, I'll go through and retag a million old questions. In the mean time, I retag the new ones as I see them. @bra

Comment: @CodyGray no, is not. Improve a question is **extremely nuanced** (read subjective). You and me can have different ways to improving a question (votes are subjective anyways too). A support one, would actually have very objective answers instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason, can be whatever. While the tooltip says *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*, what constitute any of those elements for any user at any time can be anything at all.

But if I was to hazard a guess, my first reaction would be *"Why do you need to read a JSON file from inside an application, when the application has already consumed the data? What are you required to accomplish that you need to read synchronously a file? Why would there be a file at all?"*.

Basically, step back to the actual problem you are trying to solve. We aren't mind-readers, as you've noticed with the opening statement, so you have to **explain why** certain choices are made at all.